# Frontend show message "Merge for content type" when Upgrade magento 2.1.8 to version 2.2.2 :

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.2

Frontend show message "Merge for content type" when Upgrade magento 2.1.8 to version 2.2.2 :

```
  1 exception(s):
  Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Merge for content type '' is not 
  supported.

  Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Merge for content type '' is not 
  supported.


#0 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeService->getMergedAssets(Array, '')
#1 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(342): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->processMerge(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
#2 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(239): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetHtml(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
#3 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(226): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetGroup(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
#4 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(99): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssets(Array)
#5 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(249): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderHeadContent()
#6 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#8 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#9 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#10 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#11 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#12 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#14 {main}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please provide any solution over this.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely you have an entry on a default_head_blocks.xml file somewhere that looks like the following:

```
<link src="css/somefile.css"/>
```

The new line using Magento 2.2+ should look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="css/somefile.css" src_type="url"/>
```

I believe the same applies for js files.

Another example, for fonts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=YourFont" src_type="url"/>
```

And should look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=YourFont" src_type="url"  />
```

Notice the *href* to *src* change.

Answer (score 0):

I just use this and solved for me. try it and comment here.

bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

bin/magento setup:di:compile (Run the di:compile after production mode is set)

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Please try running these following in the right orders:

1. bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
4. bin/magento setup:di:compile
5. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Let me know if it works!